# create XMLDocument that have not any document root node

Tags: c#, xmldocument

I wants to create an xml like.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>   
<Initials>ANP</Initials>
<MedicalPracticeName>Dr. Anny</MedicalPracticeName>
<Start>2016-11-17</Start>
<Logon>
   <UserId>admin</UserId>
   <Password>abcde</Password>
</Logon>
```

by using XMLDocument class.

I have tried this code, but didn't success

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
XmlNode firstNode = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element,"Initials","http://www.google.com");
xmlDoc.AppendChild(firstNode );

firstNode.InnerText = "ANP";

XmlNode SecondNode = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "MedicalPracticeName", "http://www.google.com");
xmlDoc.AppendChild(SecondNode);

SecondNode.InnerText = "Dr. Anny";

XmlNode ThirdNode = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Start", "http://www.google.com");
xmlDoc.AppendChild(ThirdNode );

ThirdNode.InnerText = "2016-11-17";
```

Comment: Your Xml sample is not well formed. Why would you want to do something like this?

Comment: You can't. A valid Xml document requires exactly 1 root element.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Remove Root Element in C#/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17503619/how-to-remove-root-element-in-c)

Comment: I understand XMLDocument must have only one root node. But any other way, how to create the above XML. like concatenating different XMLNodes to one single XMLDocument.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine, your issue is with XML itself, you should follow some standards, or use another format if you can. If you don't follow it, you or anyone else working with the files in the future may have some trouble to work with it.

You may check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071237/are-there-coding-standards-for-xml-files?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) and also the [W3C specifications](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/)